# Can One Frame Be Rotated In A .mov File?

Tags: video-editor

I have a .mov file that is a slide show of many pictures set to music. One of the images was not rotated properly when the movie was made, it needs to be rotated 90 degrees to the right. Is there a way to just rotate that one image or group of frames that composes that image in the movie or does the .mov need to be recreated with the file correctly rotated?

Comment: Welcome! Sure, it is possible to rotate that one section, but we'll need some more details to help you figure out if you should do it. Did the problem image get cropped (you can't get back what was cut off)? Was it shrunk down (it may not look great blown back up)? What is the quality of the file you have and what quality do you need (the quality will probably get worse because you have to re-encode)? What tool do you want to use and what is your skill level?

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the reply! The image is not cropped or shrunk. It is a portrait image that was placed like a landscape image so it'll end up getting smaller when it is rotated. The current file is 720p and keeping the new file as 720p is fine. I downloaded Davinci Resolve. I know my way around software pretty good but my skill level with video editing and Davinci is more or less 0. If there is a better/easier tool for what I'm trying to do that would be fine.

Comment: The resolution isn't the only thing that can affect the quality. Codec and bit rate are more important. But give it a shot () and see how it goes. Davinici Resolve should be fine to use, but I'm an engineer who hasn't touched an editor in years, so I can't give you any hints there. Sorry!

Comment: Thank you. I have figured out how to rotate the whole thing which doesn't work but not frame by frame yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You probably need to do something like this: duplicate the clip, split the original clip on the timeline cutting out the rotated part, add the duplicate to the timeline just for the rotated part and rotate that.

Comment: Thank you for the help!